# What's the best structure of a joint table?

Tags: sql, indexing

I would like to know what's the best structure for joint tables ?

I usually set an id as a primary key, and add 2 columns for the 2 foreign keys.

I wonder if it is better to take of the id primary key, and create an index with the 2 foreign keys instead.

Any advice ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please follow this guide so the community can help you: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am using mysql. I didn't provide an example as I was just asking for a general rule of thumb good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most design questions, the answer is that it depends on your use case.

In the majority of cases that I've built, there were reasons to reference the relationship directly, in which case the PK on the bridge/junction table provides a way to do that. If the table really *only* exists to enforce the many-to-many relation, then it doesn't necessarily need that additional column. But then, I suppose, you're rolling the dice that such a use case will never come up in the future.

That said, I've done it both ways, but my default, like yours, is to include a primary key column on the bridge, and, almost always, to also index the foreign key fields as well.

Comment: thanks a bunch. this is neat.